# Proof of if a function is continous and one-to-one, then the inverse of the function is also continuous.

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, inverse-function

I constructed a proof that may be invalid. Is this proof rigorous enough/usable?

Prove: $f$ is a function which is continuous on the interval $I$ (the range of $f$ is on the interval $J$) and $f$ has an inverse. Prove the inverse of $f$ is continuous on $J$.

Proof: If $f$ has an inverse, that means $f$ is one-to-one and also is strictly monotonic. Let's assume $f$ is always increasing. We must prove that the definition of continuity holds for all inputs on the inverse function in the interval $J$, with $y_0$ being any input on it (and $x_0$ being the corresponding $x$ value to $y_0$ on $f$):

$$\lim_{y \to y_0}f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(y_0)$$

We know, because $f$ is always increasing, that

$f(x_0 - \epsilon) < y < f(x_0 + \epsilon)$

for any $x_0 \in I$ and any $\epsilon \gt 0$

We also know, for some $y$ and any $\delta \gt 0$ that

$f(x_0) - \delta < y < f(x_0) + \delta$.

choose sufficiently small $\delta$ so that

$f(x_0 - \epsilon) < f(x_0) - \delta$ and $f(x_0) + \delta < f(x_0 + \epsilon)$.

So, for some $y$ such that

$f(x_0) - \delta < y < f(x_0) + \delta$.

$y_0 - \delta < y < y_0 + \delta$

$-\delta < y - y_0 < \delta$

$\vert y - y_0 \vert < \delta$,

then

$f(x_0 - \epsilon) < f(x_0) - \delta < y < f(x_0) + \delta < f(x_0 + \epsilon)$.

$f(x_0 - \epsilon) < y < f(x_0 + \epsilon)$

$x_0 - \epsilon < f^{-1}(y) < x_0 + \epsilon$

$-\epsilon < f^{-1}(y) - x_0 < \epsilon$

$-\epsilon < f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(y_0) < \epsilon$

$| f^{-1}(y) - f^{-1}(y_0) | < \epsilon$ for any $\vert y - y_0 \vert < \delta$.

Therefore, the limit definition of continuity holds for any arbitrary point $(y_0, x_0)$ on the inverse function, so if the function $f$ is continuous on $I$ and has an inverse, then the inverse is continuous on $J$.

Is this proof valid? Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are we assuming that $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$?  You haven't actually said so.

Comment: I just clarified that and put some new intervals on the function. Does it make more sense now or is this not helpful?

Comment: Your proof is fine, but you can just observe that $f(I)$ is an open interval for each open interval $I$. That is, $f$ is continuous and open, so $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: That is nice and simple. Thank you!

Comment: @Matematleta why $f(I)$ is an open interval for each open interval $I$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous and increasing so since $I=(a,b)$ is connected, $f(I)$ is either an open, closed or half open interval. Wlog $f(I)=[c,d)$. Then, there is an $a'\in I$ such that $f(a')=c.$ But then, choosing any $a<a''<a'$, we have $f(a'')<f(a')=c$ so $f(a'')\notin f(I)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: so you excluded the case that it is half-open .... what about the case that it is closed? @Matematleta

Comment: The same proof applies-